# Jmeter, read BLOB (Which contains an XML) using Jmeter

Tags: oracle, groovy, jmeter

I have a database table in which one column has a BLOB data, which can contain a text or an XML [Please do not ask why, somehow a dev made this choice]. I want to read the BLOB data and save it in a file. Can anyone help me on how to read the BLOB data?

I have the following JSR 223, POST processor (Groovy Code):

```
byte[] blobByte = vars.getObject("gaurav").get(0).get("TEXT");
String blob = new String(blobByte);
log.info(blob);
```

However, I get the following error:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method java.lang.String#<init>.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [class [B]
    [class [C]
    [class java.lang.String]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:223) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:44) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:931) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:569) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:490) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
```

Can anyone help me what is wrong in my logic?

PS: I refer this page for the conversion logic : https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-blob-from-a-mysql-database-with-jmeter

Comment: Your error is because blobByte is null, so groovy doesn't know which constructor you mean for string

Comment: Is this an oracle database?

Comment: Yes, the DB is oracle

Answer (score 0):

In the article you're referring to the `TEXT` is the name of the column, I strongly doubt that your column has this name therefore your `blobByte` is null therefore your BLOB reading logic fails.

Check which variables are being produced by your [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination, your approach will work only if you see `gaurav` JMeter Variable with the value of `java.sql.Blob`

See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article for more information on working with JDBC Result Sets in JMeter tests

Comment: I see the following in the result tree: gaurav=[{test=oracle.sql.BLOB@251897}, {test=oracle.sql.BLOB@131f215}, {test=oracle.sql.BLOB@1723a4}]